# SQL Server, tinyint and the case of the missing zeroes

Tags: sql-server-2008, tinyint

I have a table in SQL Server 2008, which has a column having datatype `tinyint`. Recently I noticed some very strange behavior. When doing something like

```
update mytable 
set mytinyint = 0 
where id = 1
```

The value in the column `mytinyint` is **`NULL`**. The query below

```
update mytable 
set mytinyint = NULL
where id = 1
```

also results in the value being `NULL`. And finally this query

```
update mytable 
set mytinyint = 1
where id = 1
```

sets the value to to `1`.

So my question is: why can't a store the value `0` in a column which should be capable of storing any value between `0` and `255` and `NULL`??

Comment: A [quick test](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/77224) shows that there must be something else going on for you. `tinyint` can have `0` as value. Do you have a trigger on your table?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. There actually was a trigger in the database which did exactly that.